# OperationsMetadata wrong ows:Get xlink:href

Tags: geoserver

I have a wrokspace called WMS in Geoserver. I have a problem with this name when I execute the following command for the WFS service: https://wms2.um.warszawa.pl/geoserver/WMS/wfs?request=getcapabilities.
Well, in the section ows:OperationsMetadata
I have:

ows:HTTP
<ows:Get xlink:href="http://wms2.um.warszawa.pl/geoserver/WMS/WMS/wfs"/>
<ows:Post xlink:href="http://wms2.um.warszawa.pl/geoserver/WMS/WMS/wfs"/>
</ows:HTTP>

which is an invalid address, it should be:
http://wms2.um.warszawa.pl/geoserver/WMS/wfs.

I don't know why it happens that the WMS phrase is repeated.
With any other name it's good, only with WMS it's bad. How to change it?

Comment: that sounds like a bug, GeoServer is probably treating WMS as a special keyword somewhere in the URL handling code - the simplest answer would be to not call your workspace WMS

Comment: There may be. Only if I use the WFS name, it's fine. Probably best to change the workspace.

Comment: it's worth opening a bug so it might get fixed